# radio button is not changing by selecting

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have 2 radio button male, female. I did every thing.. when I try to select male, female radiobuton. Its not at all selecting. Here my code :

```
 @IBOutlet var btn_male: UIButton! // create outlet for radio button
 @IBOutlet var btn_female: UIButton!

 @IBAction func btn_male_female_click(sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 10:
            //male select
            if (sender.selected == true) {
                sender.selected = false;
                btn_male.selected = true;
                btn_female.selected = false;
                gender = "1"
                print("male  selected")

            }else{
                sender.selected = true;
                btn_male.selected = false;
                btn_female.selected = true;
                gender = "2"
                 print("female  selected")
            }
            break;
        case 20:
            //female select
            if (sender.selected == true) {
                sender.selected = false;
                btn_female.selected = true;

                btn_male.selected = false;
                gender = "2"
                 print("female  selected")
            }else{
                sender.selected = true;
                btn_female.selected = false;
                btn_male.selected = true;
                gender = "1"
                 print("male  selected")
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

I don't know why is not selecting. To change the images I changed the state config to selected and i kept the selected radio image.

But my problem is its not at all selecting.Please help me out.Thanks

**UPDATE:**

After i update this solution. I just check from my db and i am shwoing which gender for particular user that they already save. But i have one problem.

For example, if i select male and i save it.And when i return to my profile screen my male button is showing as selected .This is coming from db no problem in that. But when i want to change the radio button from male to female, and when i press female radio button. My male radio button is still as selected, Its not changing to unselect. If i do this for two times then its changing.

```
 @IBAction func btn_male_female_click(sender: UIButton) {
        self.selectedButton.selected = false
        self.selectedButton = sender
        self.selectedButton.selected = true
        gender = "male"
        if sender == btn_female {
            gender = "female"
        }
        else  if sender == btn_male {

            gender = "male"
        }
}
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

 if profileData.Gender .isEmpty {





        }else{
            if profileData.Gender == "male"
            {
                self.btn_male.selected = true
                self.btn_female.selected = false
            }
            else if profileData.Gender == "female"
            {
                self.btn_male.selected = false
                self.btn_female.selected = true
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Change the image for selected button, assign using `setImage:...` method, you need, hence, two image.

Comment: its already working fine mack with this code

Comment: @mack in your case you use some library for this so you have to write code according to that library.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  No dude, when i give this to client its din work. No button is selecting by my above code post dude

Comment: this code is for your button click not for viewdidload() method you have to check that in viewdidload()

Comment: @mack now what happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by simply creating declaring one more instance of  `UIButton` that holds the selected button between this two button like this.

```
@IBOutlet var btn_male: UIButton! // create outlet for radio button
@IBOutlet var btn_female: UIButton!
var selectedButton = UIButton()
```

Now use the button action like this.

```
@IBAction func btn_male_female_click(sender: UIButton) {
    self.selectedButton.selected = false
    self.selectedButton = sender 
    self.selectedButton.selected = true
    gender = "1" 
    if sender == btn_female {
         gender = "2"
    }
}
```

**Edit:** You can manage selected property like this way.

```
if !(profileData.Gender.isEmpty) {

    if profileData.Gender == "male"
    {
         self.selectedButton = self.btn_male
    }
    else if profileData.Gender == "female"
    {
         self.selectedButton = self.btn_female             
    }
    self.selectedButton.selected = true
}
```

Comment: It throws me error in this line `gender = (sender == btn_male)?; "1"; : "2"`  Asking me to add more commas

Answer (score 1):

In your code problem is

```
case 10:
        //male select
        if (sender.selected == true) {
            sender.selected = false; // btn_male selected "false"
            btn_male.selected = true; // btn_male selected "true" that's the problem
            btn_female.selected = false;
            gender = "1"
            print("male  selected")

        }
```

I hope this code will Help you

```
@IBAction func btn_male_female_click(sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 10:
        //male select
        if (sender.selected == true) {
            sender.selected = false;
            btn_female.selected = false;
            gender = "1"
            print("male  selected")

        }else{
            sender.selected = true;
            btn_female.selected = true;
            gender = "2"
            print("female  selected")
        }
        break;
    case 20:
        //female select
        if (sender.selected == true) {
            sender.selected = false;
            btn_male.selected = false;
            gender = "2"
            print("female  selected")
        }else{
            sender.selected = true;
            btn_male.selected = true;
            gender = "1"
            print("male  selected")
        }

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```